# How to return from deleting if registry key doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to delete registry value but if doesn't exist then return.

How can possible??

**Example:**

**>>> For inserting <<<**

```
  private void startup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "MyApp", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
        }
```

**>>> For Deleting<<<**

```
private void DeleteRegKey_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {           
string keyName = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName , true))
                {
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                       key.DeleteValue("MyApp");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Not Found!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                    }

                }
        }
```

**It's working fine if file exist but failed if doesn't exist.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check before doing actual delete

```
if(key.GetValue("MyApp") != null)    
    key.DeleteValue("MyApp");
else
   // do something if value doesn't exist
```